# GPIO value to Byte

Tags: byte, microcontroller, gpio

I wanna to make a simple converter.
It's simple theoritically, but I can't figure out how to achieve it.
So, here is what I wanna do:
First I will read my GPIO value from the Microcontroller, with quantity of 8.
Now, I have 8 byte of GPIO value from GPIO 1 to GPIO 8.

But, how I could convert them into a byte?

Like this: `11111000` (8 byte - before), becomes `11111000/0xFA` (1 byte - after)?
I try to use shifting, something like this:

```
a = GPIO1, a = a << 7 |
b = GPIO2, b = b << 6 |
.
.
h = GPIO8

uint8_t i = a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h
```

Unfortunately, It's not working.
Did I do it in the wrong way ?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please define `GPIO`. Is this a bit at your peripheral port or is it a 8-bit entity. If you have 8 GPIOs with a width of 8 bits for each one you can't fold it into one byte without loss of data.

Comment: Better to post the code you are using to read the inputs, than to try to describe them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice way to achieve this would be to use the combination of `struct` and `union`. With a `union`, you can access the same memory in two different ways. For example:

```
union gpio_type {
    uint8_t data;
    struct raw {
        unsigned int b0 :1;
        unsigned int b1 :1;
        unsigned int b2 :1;
        unsigned int b3 :1;
        unsigned int b4 :1;
        unsigned int b5 :1;
        unsigned int b6 :1;
        unsigned int b7 :1;
    };
};
```

With `unsigned int b0 :1;` inside the struct, you define `b0` to be of type `unsigned int`, but use only 1 bit. If you do this for all 8 GPIO bits `b0 ... b7`, you have a total size of 8 bits, which is the same size as `uint8_t`. Now `data` and `raw` will use the same memory, but you can access the memory through either variable. With that you can write the raw GPIO values into the bits of the struct and later access the whole data byte.

For example, let's create create an instance of this union and access either the `uint8_t` data, or a single bit:

```
union gpio_type my_gpio_reg;
my_gpio_reg.data = 0xA0;       % Set whole reg to 0xA0
my_gpio_reg.raw.b0 = 1;        % Set the last bit to 1 ==> 0xA1
```